# Properly configuring closure to capture results

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am writing some custom store methods for in app purchases; sort of a wrapper for SwiftyStore.  The problem I'm running into is the inability to get the results from the closures before they exit.

Any suggestions on how to properly set them up? IE: Closures...

I have a function that checks for an existing subscription and returns true if it finds one in firebase, if it doesn't then it goes out to the apple store to verify a previously purchased subscription:

```
func checkSubscription() -> Bool {
        var RetVal: Bool = false
        var retStat: String = ""
        var myVal: Bool = false

        self.rootRef.child("users").child(self.userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let mySubType = value?["subtyp"] as? String ?? ""
            // set value
            if mySubType == "" {
                // get receipt
                if self.myStore.getReceipt() == true {
                    (myVal, retStat) = self.myStore.verifyPurchase(product: "com.xxxxx.xxxxx.monthly")
                    if myVal == true && retStat == "Valid" {
                        // we have a valid product update firebase
                        print("Valid")
                    } else if myVal == true && retStat == "Expired" {
                        // we have a valid product that is expired
                        print("Expired")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // we have a purchase, verify its not expired.
                print("Purchased")
                RetVal = true
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return RetVal
    }
```

The problem here is its dropping down to the return RetVal before the closure is complete so the function could be returning an invalid value.  Not sure how I can fix this in the current setup, but any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Just pass in a closure as parameter of `checkSubscription()` and call it when your verification code is completed.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.  Thanks for the suggestion - need to do some research on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Tom's comment, if you want to return a result when the nested asynchronous function is complete, you could pass in a completion handler closure that uses the Result type that Swift offers like the following:

```
func checkSubscription(completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) {
    var RetVal: Bool = false
    var retStat: String = ""
    var myVal: Bool = false

    self.rootRef.child("users").child(self.userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let mySubType = value?["subtyp"] as? String ?? ""
        // set value
        if mySubType == "" {
            // get receipt
            if self.myStore.getReceipt() == true {
                (myVal, retStat) = self.myStore.verifyPurchase(product: "com.xxxxx.xxxxx.monthly")
                if myVal == true && retStat == "Valid" {
                    // we have a valid product update firebase
                    print("Valid")
                } else if myVal == true && retStat == "Expired" {
                    // we have a valid product that is expired
                    print("Expired")
                }
            }
        } else {
            // we have a purchase, verify its not expired.
            print("Purchased")
            RetVal = true
        }

        completion(.success(RetVal))

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(.failure(error))
    }
}
```

Calling the function using this type of completion handler would look something like this:

```
checkSubscription { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let boolValue):
        // do something with resulting boolean
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        // do something with resulting error
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird error:Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'

Comment: I added @escaping - found an article about that.

Comment: Ah, good point, I'll update my answer to include the `@escaping` syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkSubscription(completion: (_ scuess:Bool) ->()){
  var RetVal: Bool = false
        var retStat: String = ""
        var myVal: Bool = false

        self.rootRef.child("users").child(self.userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let mySubType = value?["subtyp"] as? String ?? ""
            // set value
            if mySubType == "" {
                // get receipt
                if self.myStore.getReceipt() == true {
                    (myVal, retStat) = self.myStore.verifyPurchase(product: "com.xxxxx.xxxxx.monthly")
                    if myVal == true && retStat == "Valid" {
                        // we have a valid product update firebase
                        print("Valid")
                    } else if myVal == true && retStat == "Expired" {
                        // we have a valid product that is expired
                        print("Expired")
                    }
                }
              completion(false)
            } else {
                // we have a purchase, verify its not expired.
                print("Purchased")
                completion(true)
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        }
        return RetVal
    }
```

call completion(true) whenever your retValue supposed to be true and completion(false) whenever your retValue supposed to be true

Then call this function this way:

```
checkSubscription { (sucuess) in
    if(sucuess){
       print("OK")
     }else{
        print("BAD")
     }
 }
```